# How to change an inside attributes

Tags: vuejs3

I want to do a header buttons type like :

If I call "HeaderFunction" than all selecteds will be false and only one I clicked will be true.
and watch selected attributes than=> if selected attributes are true than :class will be "selected" and all of other selected false attributes will be "nonselected" class...

How can I handle that?

```html
<template>
    <button 
        type="button" 
        selected="true"  
        :class="selected" 
        @click='HeaderFunction'
    >
        first button
    </button>
    <button 
        type="button" 
        selected="false" 
        :class="nonselected" 
        @click='HeaderFunction'
    >
        second button
    </button>
</template>

    
<script>
export default {
   data(){
      return{
       selected:'btn btn-success btn-sm',
       nonselected:'btn btn-danger btn-sm',
     }
   },
    methods: {
    callFunction: function (event) {
        var selected = event.target.getAttribute('selected');
        return  alert (selected);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an array and variable holding the currently active button:

```html
<template>
  <button v-for="(item,index) in headerList" :key="index" :class="currentButtonIndex === index ? selected : unselected" @click="chooseHeader(index)">{{ item }}</button>
</template>

<script>
export default
{
  data()
  {
    return {
      currentButtonIndex: -1,
      selected: 'btn btn-success btn-sm',
      unselected: 'btn btn-danger btn-sm',
    }
  },
  computed:
  {
    headerList()
    {
      return [
        'First button',
        'Second button',
      ]
    }
  },
  methods:
  {
    chooseHeader(index)
    {
      this.currentButtonIndex = index;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: thx I solved my problem... by the way.. can an attribute change with vuejs like jquery?

Comment: If you mean an attribute of HTML tag - of course it can change. However, since Vue is a reactive framework - it is strongly recommended to change attributes in a declarative way (from the template) rather than imperatively like jQuery (in code)

Comment: can you share me a documentations about "imperatively  change" ?

Comment: An imperative change to something like `<button ref="mybtn" selected>` would be `if(this.$refs.mybtn.hasAttribute('selected')) this.$refs.mybtn.removeAttribute('selected'); else this.$refs.mybtn.addAttribute('selected');` while a declarative way would be `<template><button :selected="selectionsArray.includes(3)">Click here</button></template>`